# Facebook php sdk v4 get unlimited messages from user inbox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get all user messages of all threads, but I only can get the 30 last messages of each thread:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/inbox?comments_limit=9999');
$response = $request->execute();
$threads = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

$comments = $threads->comments;
foreach($comments as $messages)
{
    foreach($messages as $message)
    {
        echo $message->from->name.'<br />';
        echo $message->message.'<br /><br />';
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I get unlimited messages?

Thanks

Comment: at any given time you can get only a limited amount of data out of the FB API. You can't get all the data at once at all. FB had applied this restrictions due to resource wastage.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement paging to get all entries: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging

For example, you could use a recursive function for that. Keep in mind that you may run into API call limits if there are a lot of messages.

You can also increase the limit a bit, but the maximum is usually 100: `/me/inbox?limit=100`